# Django-Haystack giving attribute error?

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I am trying to use Haystack and Whoosh with my Django app. I followed the steps on Haystack docs, but i am getting this error when i do a search

```
AttributeError at /search/
'module' object has no attribute 'get_model'
```

search_indexes.py -

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from movies.models import Movie


class MovieIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')

    def get_model(self):
        return Movie

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

I couldn't find help on this error anywhere, what am i doing wrong?

Stacktrace -

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=The+Revenant&models=movies.movie

Django Version: 1.9.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'whoosh',
 'haystack',
 'registration',
 'crispy_forms',
 'movies',
 'mptt')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/home/dr_sherlock/movienalyse/virmovienalyse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/dr_sherlock/movienalyse/virmovienalyse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/dr_sherlock/movienalyse/virmovienalyse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/views.py" in __call__
  51.         self.results = self.get_results()

File "/home/dr_sherlock/movienalyse/virmovienalyse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/views.py" in get_results
  91.         return self.form.search()

File "/home/dr_sherlock/movienalyse/virmovienalyse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/forms.py" in search
  116.         return sqs.models(*self.get_models())

File "/home/dr_sherlock/movienalyse/virmovienalyse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/forms.py" in get_models
  110.                 search_models.append(models.get_model(*model.split('.')))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /search/
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_model'
```

Python 2.7.6
Django 1.9.1
Haystack 2.4.1
Whoosh 2.7.0

Comment: I think full traceback is necessary.

Comment: BTW, which versions are your Django, Haystack and Whoosh? I found some similar error with old version of Haystack which hide the real error behind.

Comment: thanx for your reply, i have updated the question as you said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks to me like a compatibility issue between the version of Haystack and Django. Django recently reworked the `get_model` system (I think in 1.9), so if you've upgraded Django and not Haystack - or perhaps vice-versa - that may be the issue.

I'm guessing the `get_model()` references in your index file are a potential red-herring, and that the issue is within the Haystack internals, as it's not able to find that method where it expects to.

Comment: That seems like the issue, what should i do?

Comment: I installed Django 1.8.8 and now it is working. Must be a problem with Django 1.9

Comment: I'd have said more likely a Haystack compatibility issue - or potentially a Whoosh compatibility issue - with Django 1.9

Comment: OMG if I could upvote you both 1000 times I would right now. This was the most ridiculous problem I have had in awhile.

Comment: I have the same error with Django==1.9 and Elasticsearch and the latest version of haystack (django-haystack==2.4.1):(, and downgrading to Django==1.8 I have no errors

Answer (score 6):

I replaced the following line in haystack\forms.py:

```
if self.is_valid():
        for model in self.cleaned_data['models']:
            search_models.append(models.get_model(*model.split('.')))
```

by this:

```
if self.is_valid():
        for model in self.cleaned_data['models']:
            model_info = model.split('.')
            search_models.append(apps.get_model(app_label=model_info[0], model_name=model_info[1]))
```

With the import

```
from django.apps import apps
```

I found the line to change simply by following the error callstack I was getting. For you, it seems to be in "/home/dr_sherlock/movienalyse/virmovienalyse/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/forms.py"

EDIT: Getting the latest version of haystack solves the issue

```
pip uninstall django-haystack
pip install git+https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack.git
```

from [Django-Haystack: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_default_manager'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852424/django-haystack-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-default-manager)

Comment: Getting the latest version of haystack worked for me too

Answer (score 0):

Just define a new Method in your Search Index class (search_indexes.py)

```
from .models import mymodel
from haystack import indexes
class MyIndex(indexes.SearchIndex,indexes.Indexable):

     def get_model(self):
        return mymodel
```